# If were creatures obeyed the physical conservation of mass, what animals could they easily change into from people in their natural range?

Tags: science-based, shapeshifters

In my world, all animals can have a were equivalent. The requirements are that they must have blood and that they cannot change mass. However, that's not necessarily a limit when it comes to the possible animals! A were elephant who wants to turn into an elephant merely has to spend up to six months eating a lot of food in order to swiftly grow into and elephant. A were chinese hamster merely has to ditch most of their flesh and then eat their way back into a human being. (How they stay sentient is being hand waved in the story so don't worry about it.)

Small female werewolves are some of the best known ones because they can easily turn from a hundred and nineteen pound human into a hundred and nineteen pound wolf and back. Same with cassoways but the problem I was having was figuring out what other animals would match. Cassowaries work because the people who live near them are smaller then say the average american. So what other animals would also work? The requirements are: live nearby the average weighed person and also have their weight range be within the average weight range of the ethnicities with a give or take of five pounds.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, since you have already given a rage going from the elephant to the hamster. Do you want a list of all the animals bigger than a hamster and smaller than an elephant?

Comment: wolves are fine for medieval humans, who were shorter and less massive. What is the timeframe of the question.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica the OP wants a list of animals of the same mass as humans, which they could get with a few minutes on Wikipedia.

Comment: @John Do you have any advice on how to reword this? I'm looking for animals of the same mass as humans they live with. So if the average man in mexico is 165, then I wanted any animals in mexico that weighed from 160 to 170. If you could also link to where I could find such charts then that would be amazing as well. I don't mind doing work but I wasn't having much luck but the list of mammals in mexico on wikipedia couldn't be organized by state and not all animals cover all of mexico. Also, I can't find the list you're talking about animals with the same mass as humans. If you could share it,

Comment: that would be super appreciated.

Comment: Your big problem is humans cover a fairly wide range of heights wherever they are, then you have some populations with distinct differences mostly in Africa.  Many animals have fairly wide ranges as well. so for most places really all you are asking is for a list of animals in a certain mass range. Your best bet is to narrow the humans down to a single specific population at a time, of course you can answer that question with five minutes on Wikipedia. wiki Mexico wildlife, each animals wiki and google page will have body mass.

Comment: One big problem you will have is modern country boarders don't lineup with with biome boarders. so to make this answerable you really will have to narrow it down to a single country, just the answer for Mexico will include several distinct biomes, Russia would cover dozens.

Comment: U fixated on a problem which does not exists, as mentiont, people have range of masses, but another side of the coin is that new born baby elephant weigths as fit human, so if an skinny human converts he converts in skinny newborn. All animals which have a greater mass than humans have their newborns of lesser mass. And what u describe is just shapesifting so there is no essencial difference between forms, so convert  yourself to whatever, just scaled up/down accordingly by mass. Due your handwavium the q is quite pointles at its core, at least as it is described by now.